# Intersected cone, a practical problem

Tags: solid-geometry

This is the maths representation of a problem which I have from the practice.

We have an interested cone with a diameter of the base $d$, height $h$ and the angle $\alpha$ as shown on the drawing. A plane $\gamma$ has been created which passes through the edge of the cone $A$ and again through the cone at point $B$ and the angle towards the base is $\beta$. 
Generally, the result section between the plane and the cone should be ellipse.
The question is - is there any combination of values of $d, h, \alpha$ so that the section is circle?

A drawing of the problem can be found here: 
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I can't see your picture, but the intersection of a plane and cone will be a circle only if the plane is perpendicular to the axis of the cone.